# How to export a small subset of data (full structure) with HeidiSQL

Tags: mysql, heidisql

We are managing our web app data with HeidiSQL and MySQL.

It is a full database structure with users, listings, transactions, etc.

We would like to keep the same full structure, however just export out a small sample of the available data so that our freelancing dev team can work with it to test new features without allowing access to the whole dataset?

Perhaps just export all data pertaining to one or two users?

Thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 3):

With HeidiSQL you can do that in two steps.

1. At first export the structure, without data: "*Export data as SQL*"
2. The second step has to be done with more manual clicks. Click each table from which you want to export partial data, select the wanted rows in the "*Data*" tab, then rightclick and click "*Export grid data*". Select "*SQL INSERTs*" and some filename. Repeat this step for all tables you want to export partially.

Comment: Thanks Anse, the second step is done on the original data or on the full set that I have exported in step 1?

Comment: First step exports structure only, without data. So, the second is to export the data, but in a different dialog: the "Export grid rows" dialog, not via "Export data as SQL".